# Advanced Debugging & Bug Tracking Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have developed a web application which uses lots of JavaScript plugin. Consist of history.js, requirejs, jquery, bootstrap, and etc. Most of the time the application is functioning properly. But it is also frequently run into errors.

I have tried my best to track the bug. But the problem is it is very hard to reproduce the bug. It just happen randomly with different kind of problem and all the errors that I caught are report pointing to the plugin like jquery.js, history.js and etc. Not on the part of code done by me. There is no way I can get the clue to fix it.

So, what are the good method I can better tracking & fixing the bugs in JavaScript?

Thank you.

Comment: This might be out there - I have never tried it - but is it not possible to create a mimick console that sends reports to your server? Say console.report() with an ajax reauest in it. Maybe even modify console.log to do that..? Interesting though, I'll keep an eye out for answers here.

Comment: Whenever you see an error in your console that points to a line in jquery.js, or bootstrap.js, click the little red triangle to the left of it and you'll see a stack trace. This will give you line numbers to pieces of code that you wrote that your error came from, start investigating those.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your comment. But the problem is, I am using requirejs, and the error message that I get from it is somehow meaningless. Always not very useful. Really hard to trace.